# Limit growing of column with MigLayout

Tags: java, swt, miglayout

I have the following test `Shell`, using `MigLayout` I want to create a simple form (left label, right text field).
The label should take up as much space as required and the text should grow automatically up to the right edge of the parent composite.

This works great until I add a large text to the text field. The text field then grows over to the edge of the parent composite:

**short text works**
[image: short text works]
**long text grows over the edge**
[image: long text grows over the edge]

How can I configure the right column to stop growing at the right edge if the text is too long?

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

import net.miginfocom.swt.MigLayout;

public class TestShell {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setSize(400, 200);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        Composite composite = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(200, 100));

        composite.setLayout(new MigLayout("fillx"));

        Label label = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);
        label.setText("LABEL");

        Text text = new Text(composite, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setLayoutData("growx, pushx");
        //      text.setText("TEXT");
        text.setText("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

With `GridLayout` this works fine:

```
composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
...
text.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL | GridData.GRAB_HORIZONTAL));
```

Is there a way I could make `MigLayout` behave like `GridLayout` but with all the additional `MigLayout` features?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is to call `setText` after `shell.open();`

```
...
shell.open();
text.setText("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
...
```

[image]